# how to properly log the output of a console program that frequently updates "parts" of the screen, resulting in a messy log file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, logs, java

I have some Java executable (jar) that is run my some shell script from a cron job once every night. That executable does not print log statements "as usual" just by printing them out in a sequential manner like line after line (print after print), but while it processes its data its printing a single line with status data and then "overwrite" or "update" just that single line over and over again, until its done with this part of processing.

#### Examples:

A common program would output something line this:

```
Program XYZ started..<cr+lf>
processing 1<cr+lf>
processing 2<cr+lf>
processing 3<cr+lf>
im done<cr+lf>
```

Simple! I can easily redirect its output to a file and I'm done.

But the program I will have to deal with does it more like this:

```
Program XYZ started..<cr+lf>
processing 1<cr>
processing 1 - part a<cr>
processing 1 - part b<cr>
processing 1 - part c<cr>
processing 1 - part d<cr>
<cr+lf>
processing 2<cr>
processing 2 - part a<cr>
processing 2 - part b<cr>
processing 2 - part c<cr>
processing 2 - part d<cr>
<cr+lf>
processing 3<cr+lf>
im done<cr+lf>
```

but much more intensive than I showed here. So it just not always overwrite status lines, but does it *a lot* while processing. So just redirecting or appending its output to a log file does not seem to make a lot of sense here, since it will just clutter the log file with millions of screen-updates that can not be viewed and understood that easily by humans.

So my question is: is there a way or tool for programs that may behave like that to "log" or maybe "screenshot every 30 seconds" their output to a log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivially, assuming there are no vt100 escapes to handle, you might try pushing the output through

```
sed 's/\r$//; s/.*\r//'
```

or the awk equivalent

```
awk '{ sub("\r$",""); sub(".*\r",""); print}'
```

but this assumes your sed or awk can handle very long lines, as the carriage-returns obviously aren't newlines. Also, carriage-return only moves the cursor to the start of the line, but doesn't erase what is on that line, so strictly you should keep the long line before `\r\r\n` in your example.

To cope with the effectively long lines you could use `tr '\r\n' '\n\001'` to translate the `\r` to newline, and simultaneously the newlines to some other character not in your data, like control-a.

Or you can change awk's input record separator with `RS='\r'`, if your awk allows it. This gives you a script like:

```
awk -v RS='\r' '
{ if(sub("\n","")){print last;last=""}
  if($0!="")last = $0
}'
```

Comment: `program_with_ugly_output 2>&1 | sed 's/\r$//; s/.*\r//' | tee -a "$logFile"` did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use either [`script2log`](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:script2log) (simple), or `vile-pager` ([vi like emacs](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.html)) for this sort of thing.  The script handles overstrikes of the sort mentioned, as well as backspace/overstriking.  To handle cursor-movement (as you would get in editing a command-line), a simple script like this is not adequate.  The script removes ANSI-style escape sequences, however.

The [script uses `sed`](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/sample-scripts/script2log.html).  Here is just the sed-command:

```
        # Trim ordinary ANSI sequences, then OSC sequences, then backspace
        # sequences, then trailing CR's and finally overstruck sections of
        # lines.
        #
        # There are still several interesting cases which cannot be handled
        # with a script of this sort.  For example:
        #       CSI K (clear line)
        #       cursor movement within the line
        sed \
                -e 's/[[][?]\{0,1\}[;0-9]*[@-~]//g' \
                -e 's/[]][^]*//g' \
                -e 's/[]][^]*\\//g' \
                -e ':loop; s/[^]\(.\)/\1/g; t loop;' \
                -e 's/ *$//g' \
                -e 's/^.* //g' \
                -e 's/[^[]//g'
```

which contains literal escape characters rather than rely upon non-POSIX extensions.

Further reading:

- [sed - stream editor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) (POSIX)
- [ECMA-48:
  Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)